# Automapper IEnumerable<T> of class is not mapped

Tags: c#, automapper

I use ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Automapper 9.0.0.

I have the following `Order` model class:

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DatePlaced { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

and `OrderDto` class:

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DatePlaced { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OrderItemsDto> Items { get; set; }

}
```

I've written the following configurations to map from *dto* to *model* class:

```
CreateMap<OrderItemsDto, OrderItem>()                
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TotalPrice));


CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>()        
    .ForPath(dest => dest.DatePlaced, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DatePlaced))        
    .ForPath(dest => dest.OrderItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items));
    // .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderItems, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items));
```

and this is a configuration from *model* to *dto* class:

```
CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemsDto>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Product.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.Name))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Product.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.Price))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Product.Category.Name, opt => 
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.Product.Category.Name))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.TotalPrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TotalPrice));

CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForPath(dest => dest.DatePlaced, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DatePlaced))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderItems));
```

However, the `Items` is always empty, but `DatePlaced` is mapped.

I've got the following result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "datePlaced": "2020-02-09T21:48:13.347",      
        "items": []
    }
]
```

The method which returns data:

```
return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderDto>>(await _orderRepository.GetAll());
```

How can `Items` can me mapped correctly?

Comment: You haven't created a mapping for `OrderItemsDto` -> `OrderItem` (or you haven't shown it). Also, should that be `OrderItemDto` (single) rather than `OrderItemsDto` (plural)?

Comment: @John please, see my updated question

Comment: Is there a reason why you are manually setting up mappings for all these identically named fields? Is `CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>(); CreateMap<OrderItemsDto, OrderItem>();` not sufficient by itself?

Comment: @John no, there is no reason. I will try to delete themif it is ok.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are missing the mapping between
OrderItemsDto and OrderItem. 
Because of that, Automapper doesn't know how to map the items of the collection.

Adding the mappings
`OrderItemsDto -> OrderItem` and
`OrderItem-> OrderItemsDto`

Should fix the problem.

Comment: Can you try changing `return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OrderDto>>(await _orderRepository.GetAll());` to `return _mapper.Map<List<OrderDto>>(await _orderRepository.GetAll());`

Comment: Can you try `(await _orderRepository.GetAll()).Select(_mapper.Map<OrderDto>)`

Comment: ooops, it was my mistake. I just should see other `Items` and they are not empty. Thank for your time!